# Load and initialise controller dynamically in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, extjs4.2

We use extjs v4.2 and sencha touch v2.3

I'm currently working on a project that involves loading the controller dynamically. This works perfectly well in extjs for me, but I can't get the same functionality in sencha touch.

When i want to load a controller in extjs I use the following syntax

```
    var controllerLookup = 'here.app.controller.' + controllerName;

    AppName.app.getController(controllerLookup);
```

This then goes back to the server, downloads the controller and calls its init method.

I would like the exact same functionality in sencha touch. From reading the docs the syntax looks like it should work similarly, but i can't seem to get it to work. when i run the code in the console i just get an undefined. No call to the server like I do in extjs looking for the file. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong or if it's even possible to do in sencha touch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a post on the sencha forums (https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198019-How-to-load-controllers-dynamically) I was able to get it to work. The controller now loads in dynamically and calls the init method

**AppName**

The name you used in Ext.Application when defining your application in app.js or equivalent.

**Classpath**

The full namespace to you controller file

```
function addControllerDynamicallyForMobile(classPath, config) {
    var app = AppName.app.application,
        config = config || {};
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
    Ext.require(classPath, function() {
        var controllers = app.getControllerInstances();
        if (!controllers[classPath]) {
            var controller = Ext.create(classPath, Ext.apply({
                application : app
            }, config.options || {}));
            controllers[classPath] = controller;
            app.controllers.push(classPath);
            controller.init();
            if (config.callback) { config.callback.call((config.scope || this), config); }
        }
    });
};
```

calling this function

```
var controllerLookup = 'here.app.controller.' + controllerName;;
addControllerDynamicallyForMobile(controllerLookup)
```